# Java method CharAt crashes at comparing to #

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception, charat

So what I want to do is to see if a string starts with a # in a text file.
However when I call the comparison of `charAt(0)` with `#` it gives out an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at StringTranslator.main(StringTranslator.java:63)
```

The code itself looks like this(well the part that does all the comparison)

```
String line;
line = br.readLine())
if(line.charAt(0) == '#')
{
    // this is a comment line ignore it
    writer.println(line);

}
```

Any suggestions how to outcome this and make it recognize the `#` symbol? Thank you in advance!
Note: I am using `UTF-8 encoding` in both writing file in notepad and reading file in code!

Comment: It's not about the octothorp, it's that you are reading an empty string.

Comment: As a matter of fact your statement is false, I printed the string before checking it and it was there, the entire string

Comment: Hint: if you read the error message, or if you use your debugger, or if you simply add `System.out.println(line);`in your code, you can figure out what the problem is by yourself. That's the daily bread of a programmer, you'd better get used to it and do this simple analysis by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the [octothorpe](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe), it's that you are reading an empty string.

If you want to check if the line starts with `#`, handling the empty string, use:

```
line.startsWith("#")
```

Comment: Thank you! This fix worked, however I still can't figure out why it thought it was empty even so it stated that there's text within the string.

Comment: @MartinČuka While technically you are right, based on fact that in OP example we have two closing parenthesis at `line = br.readLine())` I think we can reasonably suspiect that it was copied from well known idiom `while((line = br.readLine()) != null){...}` which should prevent NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is unrelated to the `#`. You're attempting to evaluate the first character in an empty string. You should verify the string isn't empty before accessing its characters:

```
if (line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == '#')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "String index out of range: 0" means you have a string that does not have any characters, which is to say the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if string is not empty or not null and then check what character is at index 0

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(line) && line.startsWith("#")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: While StringUtils is totally unnecessary here, because startsWith works with empty strings..you are posting the same answer as 3 other people 10 min before you.

Comment: No, because startsWith will cause nullpointer exception if string is null so this is correct solution

Comment: @JacksOnF1re it also does a null check. But you are correct that the method is unnecessary: a simple null check would suffice, since you don't need to check if it is empty for the second operand to give the correct result.

Comment: I'll revoke the -1, because of the possible NPE at the end of stream, from BufferedReader.  That's a good hint. But I'll rather see this as a comment though.